# AJAX returns net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, curl, rails-api

I am having a RAILS API.

when i am calling from terminal it is giving proper results. Now i am trying to call from external application to that API.

**CURL:**

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.marketplace.v1' http://api.market_place_api.dev:3000/users/1
```

About CURL is working properly.

Now my external file is code is:

**1234.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>API Testing</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajax({
                headers: { Accept : "application/vnd.marketplace.v1"},
                url: "http://api.market_place_api.dev:3000/users/1",
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: { auth_token: "Vb6BQdPQNx9uD_wczkeW"},
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    $('div.jsonoutput').append(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Cannot get data");
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div><center><p><strong>API Request &amp; Response Testing</strong></p></center></div>

        <div class="jsonoutput"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to `application_controller`

**Controller:**

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format != 'application/json' }
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
```

**Script:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.market_place_api.dev:3000/users/1",
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: { auth_token: "Vb6BQdPQNx9uD_wczkeW"},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                $('div.jsonoutput').append(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Cannot get data");
            }
        });
    </script>
```